# Comparing a string that has 2000 values with a string that has 1 value

Tags: c++

The only part of my code that has issue is the part that compares a string that has up to 2000 lines of data with a string that has 1 piece of data (input from the user).  I added the else statement to show that the if statement is never true.  My teacher was unable to figure out why it would evaluate to false. Can anyone tell me why that statement is always false, and how to fix it?

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Assignment 5
//
//

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <fstream>//for fin and fout
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare input and output file stream
    ifstream fin;//in_s, inStream, input...
    string name[2000], inName;//name is the string for the file, inName is the users name
    string number[2000];
    char again;
    cout << "Welcome to the automated phone directory! " << endl << endl;


    //Open the file streams and associate with the actual files
    fin.open("/Users/ryoncook/Documents/School/Comp Sci/Assignments/Assignment 5/Asn Five_M/phoneNames.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed" << endl;
        exit(1);//indicates 1 error occured
    }

    for(int i=0; i < 2000; i++)//loops until desired maximum size
    {
        getline(fin,name[i]);//stores the values of the file in the string array
    }
    fin.close();

    //open number file
    fin.open("/Users/ryoncook/Documents/School/Comp Sci/Assignments/Assignment 5/Asn Five_M/phoneNums.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed" << endl;
        exit(1);//indicates 1 error occured
    }

    for(int i=0; i < 2000; i++)//loops until desired maximum size
    {
        getline(fin,number[i]);//stores the values of the file in the string array
    }
    //Close all open files
    fin.close();
    do{
    cout << "Enter the name of the person you wish to look up: " << endl;
    inName.clear();
    getline(cin,inName);//reads the name desired as a string
    for (int i=0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        if (name[i] == inName)//compares input name with file name
        {
            cout << name[i] << "'s phone number is " << number[i] << endl;//prints result
        }
        else
        {
            cout << name[i] << inName;//i ran an else statement to confirm.  The out if statement is never evaluated to be true
        }
    }

    cout << "Would you like to find another phone number? (Y or N) " << endl;
    cin >> again;
    }while (again=='y' || again=='Y');
    return 0;

}
//array for phone numbers and array for names that are both strings
//compare the 2 arrays and if they are equal, print
```

The for loop should find the name that the user entered, and if its in the file, it should select the correct name and phone number.
What actually happens is that even if the name entered is in the file, the statement is never true.

I know that the if statement is the issue because I printed out a few of the name and number strings with different numbers (number[12], name[6], etc.) and they all printed the correct name/number.

Comment: You never test if any of your getline operations have actually read anything.

Comment: @NeilButterworth good point, I forgot to include that I have.  Testing both the name and the phone number file will print out the correct number (number[12] will be the 13th number in the file, same with name[12])

Comment: It works for me - one round. After you've asked if the user want to find another number, you leave a newline in the buffer so when it becomes time to enter the name, it becomes blank. After `cin >> again;` try `cin.ignore();` - or use `getline` there too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Here's something I use: `std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, line)`

Comment: `cout << "Would you like to find another phone number? (Y or N) `  Not only this is a recurring bug, it's a horrible idea UX-wise. When you dial a number, does your phone ask you if you want to press another key? If I want to find another number, I will TYPE IT!

Comment: Wild guess: the input file has Windows newlines.

Comment: @n.m. , this is how the instructions for the assignment state it should be, even if you are right in that it is not good for the UX.